# How to initialize a method in state in a constructor that is dependent on another methods value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, state

I'm trying to initialize three functions as state in the constructor in order to get the values from those functions and have those values available in state before the first render. However, one of the functions have a variable dependent on the value of a previous function and so I get an error.

How would I fix this problem? Code is below!

App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import Calendar from "./Calendar"

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Calendar />
        </div>    

    )
}

export default App;
```

Calendar.js file

```
import React from "react";


class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

    this.state = {
        //curLastDate() is dependent on lastDayOfMonth()
        lastDayOfMonth: this.storeLastDate(),
        currentLastDate: this.curLastDate()
    }
}
    /*
    Stores the last date of all months of the current year
    Format: [ ["Thu", "Jan", "31", "2019]... ]
    */
    storeLastDate() {
            let date, 
                string, 
                lastDate, 
                list = [];

            date = new Date();

            for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {

                lastDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), i, 0);
                string = lastDate.toDateString().split(" ");
                list.push(string);
            }

            return list;
    }  

/*
Finds the matching month of current date
*/
curLastDate() {

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.lastDayOfMonth.length; i++) {
        if (this.state.currentDate[1] === this.state.lastDayOfMonth[i][1]) {
            console.log(this.state.lastDayOfMonth[i][1]);
            return this.state.lastDayOfMonth[i][1];
        }
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        null
        )
    }

}
export default Calendar;
```

Ultimately, I want to initialize the values I get from the functions to the state before React has its first render. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: "Cannot read property 'lastDayOfMonth' of undefined". So it looks like the function storeLastDate doesn't finish before curLastDate() although I thought it would because of  vanilla js top to bottom parsing.

Comment: did you try my suggestion below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the values in componentDidMount and pass a callback to `.setState()`.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    lastDayOfMonth: [],
    currentLastDate: [],
    currentDate: new Date(),
  };
}

storeLastDate = () => {
  let date,
    string,
    lastDate,
    list = [];

  date = new Date();

  for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
    lastDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), i, 0);
    string = lastDate.toDateString().split(' ');
    list.push(string);
  }

  return list;
}

 /*
  Finds the matching month of current date
*/
curLastDate = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.state.lastDayOfMonth.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.currentDate[1] === this.state.lastDayOfMonth[i][1]) {
      console.log(this.state.lastDayOfMonth[i][1]);
      return this.state.lastDayOfMonth[i][1];
    }
  }
}

componentDidMount = () => {

  const lastDayOfMonth = this.storeLastDate();

  this.setState({
    lastDayOfMonth: lastDayOfMonth
  }, () => {
     this.setState({ currentLastDate: this.curLastDate() });
   }) // curLastDate as callback, which will be executed after setting state
}
```

Comment: `curLastDate` doesn't look good, I think it will fail, as it uses `currentLastDate` before it is even set.

Comment: I tried it out but it doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to have a callback function if the function that's taking in the callback hasn't formerly declared any parameters?

Comment: yes, if the fucntion depends on state values, after the first function sets state data the callback function will be executed.

Comment: Oh woops, so the first time I tried your method, I changed the state from currentLastDate: this.curLastDate() to currentLastDate: "". But I reverted it back to currentLastDate: this.curLastDate() and then I get the same error.

Comment: so `currentDate` should be initialized to the current date?

Comment: currentLastDate, but yeah, that's the goal. Doesn't this kind of thing occur a lot in react though? I just assumed there would be some standard solution.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! You saved me! I just have one more question, do you think using callbacks in these types of situations is a common occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

If you re-use your function `curLastDate`, just pass `lastDayOfMonth`

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function Calendar() {
    //curLastDate() is dependent on lastDayOfMonth()
    const [lastDayOfMonth, setLastDayOfMonth] = useState();
    const [currentLastDate, setCurrentLastDate] = useState();

    useEffect(async () => {
        const list = await storeLastDate();
        setLastDayOfMonth(list);
        const curLastDateRet = curLastDate(list);
        setCurrentLastDate(curLastDateRet);
    }, []);

    const storeLastDate = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let date,
                string,
                lastDate,
                list = [];

            date = new Date();

            for (let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {

                lastDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), i, 0);
                string = lastDate.toDateString().split(" ");
                list.push(string);
            }
            resolve(list);
        });
    }

    /*
    Finds the matching month of current date
    */
    const curLastDate = lastDayOfMonth => {
        for (let i = 0; i < lastDayOfMonth.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.currentDate[1] === lastDayOfMonth[i][1]) {
                console.log(lastDayOfMonth[i][1]);
                return lastDayOfMonth[i][1];
            }
        }
    }

    return (
        <></>// some content here
    )

}
export default Calendar;
```